# Does New Relic supports openJDK12?

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, newrelic-platform, openjdk-12

```
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
PS <path>
```

Does new relic has different version of jar for openJDK 12 ? 
I am running with new relic 5.10.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java agent for New Relic supports OpenJDK and AdoptOpenJDK JVM versions 7 to 15 for Linux, Windows, and OS X:

- [Requirements to install the agent](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-java-agent#jvm)

What happens when you restart the application? Does the error prevent startup or does it recover and continue and begin reporting?

Comment: Update:  Oddly enough, starting with the New Relic Java Agent 7.0.0, we no longer support JDK7.  But version prior to this still do.